# What is the equivalent for 'www-data' for CentOs?

Tags: chown

CentOs doesn't recognise www-data but want to change ownership on my files folder. All my folders are owned by root at the moment. Confused as to what should be owned by apache and what she be owned by me the root user? Also when it says root root does that mean root user me and group apache root?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is `apache` user instead of `www-data` in Centos.

Comment: is root same as apache?

Comment: nope. they're different users. data should be owned by `apache` to be able to modify them via your web scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you can run `sudo chgrp -R apache YOUR_FOLDER`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/207107)

Comment: @RomeoNinov This may be a wrong answer but it does try to answer the question. In any case it is not a comment posted as an answer due to a lack of rep. How did this comment get an upvote...